# replace NOT IN with JOIN

Tags: mysql, sql, count

I need a replacement NOT IN with join . How do I do this because the results are different with this query.

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM requests 
        WHERE 
            isApproved='1' AND 
            softDelete='0' AND 
            requestID NOT IN ( 
                SELECT 
                    DISTINCT requestID 
                FROM consulting 
                WHERE 
                    softDelete='0' AND 
                    isApproved='1' AND
            )
```

Comment: Please add sample data and expected result

Comment: solved problem by https://stackoverflow.com/a/71294919/18000605

Comment: `the results are different with this query` Different than what?

Comment: this query return count 0, but my query returned 5 count

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as total FROM requests AS R
   LEFT JOIN
   (
      SELECT 
                DISTINCT requestID 
            FROM consulting 
            WHERE 
                softDelete='0' AND 
                isApproved='1' AND
   ) X ON R.requestID =X.requestID 
    WHERE R.isApproved='1' AND R.softDelete='0' 
       AND X.requestID  IS NULL
```

Could you please try something like this